# Unable to use js-ctypes.jsm in xulrunner 8.0 and latest versions

Tags: xulrunner, gecko, jsctypes

*(I am not building an extension I am building my sample app)*
In xulrunner 1.9.2 I am able to use:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
```

and comfortably making a native call (.dll) on Windows. I am executing my `application.ini` using gre (Gecko runtime environment 1.9.2) which had modules folder and `ctypes.jsm`.

In latest xulrunners 7.0, 8.0 nad 9.0 GRE's there is no `modules` folder. I tried to use Xulrunner SDK's. In that in bin/modules the `ctypes.jsm` is present.

But I do not know what to give in `Components.utils.import("**********");`.
Can someone clarify my question?

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Firefox, Thunderbird, SeaMonkey and XULrunner use `omni.ja(r)` instead of separate resources. You should find `ctypes.jsm` stored inside. You can still use the same `resource:` URI to access it though. (Firefox Sync does this for instance.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am able to find it.